# Lazy Loading vendor package while excluding it from vendor.js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I currently have a large web app coded using Laravel and Vue.js. There are several scripts that I have installed via NPM that are only fired on a few pages. I've tried to Lazy Load and Code Split, but I can't seem to figure out how to exclude the file from the main vendor.js file while still compiling it as a webpack chunk.

Example:

**vue-tel-input is only used on a few of my Vue components.**

I've tried both

```
const VueTelInput = () =>
    Promise.all([
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunk-vue-tel-input" */ 'vue-tel-input'),
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunk-vue-tel-input" */ 'vue-tel-input/vue-tel-input.css'),
    ]).then(([{ VueTelInput }]) => VueTelInput);
```

and

```
const { VueTelInput } = await import(
        /*webpackChunkName:"vue-tel-input"*/"vue-tel-input"
    );
```

In my component file.

I can't seem to find the right code to create the new chunk and exclude the vue-tel-input from being included in the vendor.js file.